# Why was my answer downvoted?

Tags: discussion

I would like to know why my answer was downvoted eventhough it answered OP's question.

Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26626769/3905567).

Comment: We can't know why anyone downvotes.  Voting is anonymous.

Comment: Just downvoted it as well. A plain "try this" followed by a code dump is never useful; also, your solution is rather unintuitive and complicated - using side effects of a list comprehension to fill another list is very bad style. The solutions with `zip` are the way to go. So, your answer was downvoted because it's a bad answer.

Comment: I'm going to up vote *this* question, as I'm assuming you asked this because you genuinely wanted to know the answer. I agree with everything Louis said in his answer, and I hope you can apply it in the future.

Comment: Oh; and your avatar picture is terrifying. I could barely get two sides on those original things!

Comment: I got a similar situation. Though my answer is the first one and can resolve the problem, it's the answer to the question and the questioner choose the answer from itself.
My answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61941469/my-local-volume-for-mongodb-gets-permission-deneied-when-running-docker-compose/62185391#62185391

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible for us to know what the downvoter thought.

Here's a bit of speculation: perhaps the downvoter thought your solution was cumbersome compared to the elegance of the other solutions. You may think this is not a valid reason to downvote but there is no system in place to evaluate the validity of votes. (Except in the case of vote *fraud* which is not the case here.)

Comment: The answer being "inelegant" is a very good reason to downvote. OPs answer was the equivalent of writing a for loop as `for i in range(len(somelist)): dosomething(somelist[i])` instead of the pythonic `for e in somelist: dosomething(e)`. IMO answers with bad code should be downvoted so that people don't pick up bad habits from SO answers.